# 8 Bishops to occupy whole board [Backtracking]

Tags: java, algorithm, backtracking

I have a task to write a program which sets up 8 bishops in chess board to occupy whole board. It should end up when first solution is found and print everything out. Here's my written code in Java, and I struggle with finishing it using backtracking ( that place is commented in the code).

```
/*
 * 0 - not occupied square
 * 1 - bishop standing square
 * 2 - occupied square (diagonal)
 */
public class BishopsBT {
public int [][] solution;
final int N = 8; // number of squares in column and row (chess board)
final int solved = 120; //Sum of 1's and 2's in case of all occupied board
int sum; //current sum of board

public BishopsBT(){
    solution = new int [N][N] ;
}

public void solve() {
    if(placeBishops(0)){
        //print the result
        clear(); // clears all 2's
        for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < N; j++) {
                System.out.print(" " + solution[i][j]);
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
    } else{
        System.out.println("NO SOLUTION EXISTS");
    }
}

public boolean placeBishops (int bishop){

    for (int row = 0; row < N; row++) {
        // check if bishop can be placed
        if (canPlace(solution, row, bishop)) {
            // place the bishop
            solution[row][bishop] = 1;  
            }
        }

    if (allSpaceOccupied()) {
        return true;
    } else {
        // SOME BACKTRACKING CODE HERE
        return false;
    }

    }

// check if bishop can be placed at matrix[row][column]
public boolean canPlace(int[][] matrix, int row, int column) {

    // we need to check all diagonals
    // whether no bishop is standing there

    for (int i = row, j = column; i >= 0 && j >= 0; i--, j--) {
        if (matrix[i][j] == 1) {
            return false;
        }
    }

    for (int i = row, j = column; i >= 0 && j < matrix.length; i--, j++) {
        if (matrix[i][j] == 1) {
            return false;
        }
    }

    for (int i = row, j = column; i < matrix.length && j >= 0; i++, j--) {
        if (matrix[i][j] == 1) {
            return false;
        }
    }

    for (int i = row, j = column; i < matrix.length && j < matrix.length; i++, j++) {
        if (matrix[i][j] == 1) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    // if we are here that means we are safe to place Bishop
    return true;
}

public boolean allSpaceOccupied() {

    // clears previously occupied space
    clear();

    // occupies new space
    for (int i = 0; i < solution.length; i++) {
        for ( int j = 0; j < solution.length; j++) {
    if (solution[i][j] == 1) diagonalOccupy(i,j);
        }
    }
    sum = 0;
    // counts sum of occupied space
    for (int i = 0; i < solution.length; i++) {
        for ( int j = 0; j < solution.length; j++) {
    sum += solution [i][j];
        }
    }

    if (sum == solved) return true;
    // else
    return false;
}

public void diagonalOccupy(int row, int column) {
    // writes 2 in each bishop's occupied square
    for (int i = row, j = column; i >= 0 && j >= 0; i--, j--) {
        if (solution[i][j] == 0) {
            solution[i][j] = 2;
        }
    }

    for (int i = row, j = column; i >= 0 && j < solution.length; i--, j++) {
        if (solution[i][j] == 0) {
            solution[i][j] = 2;
        }
    }

    for (int i = row, j = column; i < solution.length && j >= 0; i++, j--) {
        if (solution[i][j] == 0) {
            solution[i][j] = 2;
        }
    }

    for (int i = row, j = column; i < solution.length && j < solution.length; i++, j++) {
        if (solution[i][j] == 0) {
            solution[i][j] = 2;
        }
    }

}
 // clears all 2's on the board
public void clear() {
    for (int i = 0; i < solution.length; i++) {
        for ( int j = 0; j < solution.length; j++) {
            if (solution[i][j] == 2) solution[i][j] = 0;
        }
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    BishopsBT q = new BishopsBT();
    q.solve();
}
}
```

The thing is that at the moment my program puts bishops in first column and this layout does not occupy all space. Of course, I could simply put everything in third column and problem is solved. However, I have to use backtracking and have no idea how. If you have any ideas or tips, I would be really glad to hear them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your solution assumes that all bishops must be placed in different rows. This is not true for all solutions. (There is a solution where all bishops are in the third or fourth column. You are not looking for all solutions, but if you were, you'd be missing out on many solutions by this assumption.)

You also don't need the `canPlace` check: There is no restriction that the bishops can't threaten each other. (This might be a valid technique to speed up the search, but again, you'll miss out on some solutions when you apply it. If you want to use it, there's no need to check all diagonal cells for already placed bishops; it is enough to check whether the current cell has been marked as "occupied" or threatened.)

If you are going to use a brute force approach with backtracking, you could test all possible combinations of bishops. That's C(64, 8) or 4,426,165,368 combinations.

You can cut down on the possibilities drastically, but not by assuming that bishops must be in diferent rows. Instead, note that your solution consists of two independent solutions. A bishop on a white square can only threaten white squares and a bishop on a black square can only threaten black squares. So find a solution to place four bishops on the board that threaten all white squares. Then

(If you want to find all solutions, find all *k* sub-solutions and combine them to *k*² complete solutions.)

This separation of cases cuts down the possible arrangements to test to C(32, 8), or 35,960. Your strategy to consider only configurations where there is exaclty one bishop per row checks 8^8 (about 16 million) possibilities. It misses some solutions and checks meny configurations where not four bishops are on white squares and four on black squares.

The principle of backtracking was given in the other answer. If you label the 32 white squares like this:

```
01  02  03  04
  05  06  07  08
09  10  11  12  
  13  14  15  16
17  18  19  20
  21  22  23  24
25  26  27  28
  29  30  31  32
```

you can use an recursive approach like this one (in pseudo-Java):

```
bool place(int i, int start) {
    if (i == 8) {
        if (allOccupied()) {
           print();
           return true;
        }
    } else {
        for (int j = start, j < 32; j++) {
            int row = j / 4;
            int col = 2 * (j % 4) + row % 2;

            // add bishop at (col, row)
            // save occupancy matrix
            // add threat by (col, row) to matrix

            if (place(i + 1, j + 1)) return true;

            // revert matrix to saved matrix
            // remove bishop from (col, row)
       }
    }

    return false;
}
```

and start it with

```
place(0, 0);
```

Comment: It was extremly helpful, as you managed to explain it very technically and I really appreciate that. I re-wrote code using your advice, but I still have no idea what to do in case if (i == 8)  and all space is not occupied. I tend to believe it should be some kind of else branch.

Comment: Appendix: I could simply return false, but in that case program will only try to change the eight's bishop position and I will never come up with solution. In that case I have to go more than one step backward.

Comment: If you return `true` only if you have found a solution and propagate the `true` value to the calling recursive function before reverting the state of the board, the board should have all bishops placed correctly when a solution is found. (The line `if (place(i + 1, j + 1)) return true;` above does that: When you return `true`, do so immediately without cleaning up.)

Answer (score 0):

You should do something like this :

```
public boolean placeBishops (int bishop){
    if(bishop == 8){
        if(allSpaceOccupied()){
            //Print the board here, i.e found the solution
            //also check the indexing of the bishop,
            //i have assumed that they start from 0
            return true;
        }else{
            return false;
        }
    }
    for (int row = 0; row < N; row++) {
        // check if bishop can be placed
        if (canPlace(solution, row, bishop)) {
            // place the bishop
            solution[row][bishop] = 1;
            boolean found = placeBishops(bishop+1);
            if(found == true) return true;
            solution[row][bishop] = 0;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

we can check if a place is good for a paticular bishop or not, and accordingly increment the bishop count, if we do not find the solution going down that path, we reset the `solution array` for the current bishop index and the corresponding row for that bishop, so that we can look for another possible solution.

Comment: This would work fine if canPlace method checked every condition (like in queens problem: you just check whether there are no queen in row, column or diagonal and place it). Here canPlace method just checks whether there is no bishop in square's diagonals ( because that would be non-sense to put bishop in such place). However, it also means that we can place 8 and all space would be not occupied. So I believe we have to include allSpaceOccupied() method somehow...

Comment: What exactly does allspaceoccupied function do??

Comment: It checks whether all space is occupied, and returns true or false.
For example, using canPlace we can place bishops like this:
1 x x x x x x x  
  1 x x x x x x 0  
  1 x x x x x 0 0  
  1 x x x x 0 0 0  
  1 x x x x 0 0 0  
  1 x x x x x 0 0  
  1 x x x x x x 0  
  1 x x x x x x x   

However, not all space is occupied here, so we have to look for different solution

Comment: So to make to make it clear when we reach a possible solution we check allSpaceOccupied function for checking that this possible solution is correct or not ?? If that is the case then a simple check when we reach the solution is required !

Comment: So okey, at this moment my program will put everything in first column and after check it will appear that this is bad solution. But all bishops are placed and I have to start over somehow. I am not explaining well probably or I don't understand something..

Comment: Thank you. I will try to use your blueprint to finish my code

Comment: @uSeemSurprised: You are returning true for both the cases in your code when you are handling the case: bishop == 8. You should return false also.